# Fixing error while loading shared libraries: libpng12.so.0 when Installing Teensyduino in Kali

Tags: linux, teensy, kali-linux

I installed Teensyduino on my Arduino. However, the Teensyloader does not work. It throws this error when I try to run it:

> teensy.64bit: error while loading shared libraries: libpng12.so.0:
>   cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I've tried installing `lib32ncurses5` and `lib32z1` but that did not work.

How can I fix this?

Comment: It says there is not `libpng` on your system. I'm not familiar with Kali, but if [this thread](https://forums.kali.org/showthread.php?32909-kali-and-libpng) is correct, you'll have to compile from source

Comment: @Munir a Ubuntu source should work on Kali correct? http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/libpng12-0

Answer (score 9):

Following Munir's tip, I downloaded the appropriate package for my computer from https://packages.debian.org/jessie/libpng12-0.

Ran the following in my console:

```
dpkg -i libpng12-0_1.2.50-2+deb8u2_amd64.deb; apt-get install -f
```

Remember to run the code from the same directory as the .deb file.

Comment: I recently installed pop_os and had this error when using image related webpack plugins, this solved the problem for me as well. Thanks!